# While highlighting the text from a string using spans creating problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I am new to `webDevelopment`. I have a string , and I want to highlight some part of the strings like 10-15 things I want to highlight. Now I do have the offsets as well, like start and end of the text which I want to highlight from that string. SO, When in the loop first gets highlighted then it adds the span tag there with class mark, because of this the indexes are getting changed, then when it try to highlight the second then it does not get the perfect match because the offsets are now changed. So, How Can I match the exact text with the span tags or without that ?

```
$scope.highlight = function(content,startoffset,endoffset){return content.replace(content.substring(startoffset, endoffset), '<span class="' + className + '">$&</span>');}

.mark {background-colour = yellow;}
```

Can any please help me with this, This is really getting messy for me.

Comment: Don't replace the original string, apply your changes to a temp string.

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I do this

Answer (score 0):

Refer this https://plnkr.co/edit/j5VCCjCHN60l0QNSTtLo?p=preview. I replaced your mark up with "**" as it is easy to show sample example.

```
  function stringReplace(content, startoffset, endoffset, previousOffset) {
    _temp = _temp.concat(content.substring(previousOffset || 0, startoffset));
    _temp = _temp.concat('**');
  }
```

Comment: Every thing is in one p tag its a string

Comment: use _temp, it has the complete string.